# Here maps routing that considers on which side of the street the destination has to be

Tags: android, here-api

We are using here-maps-SDK for point-to-point truck navigation in our Android app. Is it possible to consider the **side of the street** and force the routing-algorithm to find a route that ensures, that the destination is **on the right side** of the street?

According to some research it seems to work with following settings in the web-SDK

- sideOfStreetHint={lat},{lng}
- matchSideOfStreet=always,
- avoid[features]=difficultTurns

Is this true?
If so, how are the equivalent settings in android-SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After weeks of trying to get an answer, the so-called "premium"-support confirmed that this is currently not possible in Android-SDK.